# Formatting this date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, webforms

First of all, what is this time format called?  If I knew that much, I would have found a solution already

> 2017-02-13T13:49:00

Second.  How do I convert that to `02/13/2017` ?

Part of my problem is that I am doing this inside an `Eval` in a listView control

```
<%# Eval("pubDate", "{0:d}") %>
```

It does not work with this time format.

Comment: It's an ISO 8601 format.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: that first format that you give, do you have that object as a datetime? Or is it a string that you want to output as another string?

Answer (score -1):

Refer to - [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Try - `<%# string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Eval("pubDate")) %>`